# Screen resolution wkhtmltopdf windows virtual server

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf

I have a NT-Service installed on a virtual windows server (rackspace). This service is using wkhtmltopdf to generate a pdf from a webpage. The problem is that the PDF is generated with a screen resolution of 1024x768, default on server I guess.

Anybody faced this problem earlier? Can I change the virtual server screen resolution somehow?

Answer (score 4):

Adding switches --page-width 1600px --page-height 1200px to wkhtmltopdf did the trick. Then all printouts looks the same on all machines, no matter resolution etc.

Comment: What version of wkhtmltopdf is this? I didn't know it supported pixel values for these? Are you sure that the outputs are really using pixel equivalent width and height values? This is amazing if it actually works!

Comment: Worked for me as well on wkhtmltopdf v12.4

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while trying to set window width of `wkthmltopdf` "browser" to a specific value, because Google Form (which I wanted to save a snapshot of) was saved into A4 PDF with one-character width.

The solution for me was to use `wkhtmltoimage` instead to save the page as JPG, which didn't produce the same issue with the width as `wkhtmltopdf` did and so did not require any additional options.

While this answer does not address OP's original question, it might  come useful for others dealing with an issue like mine.